# Forward file upload details to another remote service

Tags: c#

I have a service for uploading files which works well.

Is it possible to submit a file upload to a asp.net method (like normal uploads), but then forward the upload file details to the remote service. Therefore using the asp.net method as a proxy and NOT actual upload method?

The actual file saving will be done at the remote service.

Note
I'm using c# and .net 3.5

Regards

Comment: Technically it is possible yes. There needs to be more details though. How are the files being uploaded, how does the other service receive incoming data, etc.

Comment: What are you trying to save? This will save you storage, but this will eat your bandwidth... Is that the goal?

Comment: I'm using the form file upload control <input type=file/>. The remote service is an handler that reads the Http.Context and get the file data from that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an ASP.NET method, the file MUST be uploaded to the server. However, it doesn't have to be saved using the "SaveAs" method or any other method. You can access the file directly as a stream which you can pass to your other service if you can send streams to it.

The idea is explained in this blog post (slightly different use but same idea):
http://weblogs.asp.net/meligy/archive/2008/02/18/unit-test-friendly-file-upload-handling-in-n-tier-applications.aspx

So, if your remote service call can be simplified as a method like:

```
public void MyServiceMethod(Stream inputStream) { ........ }
```

You can pass the file content from the page without saving it some way like:

```
myService.MyServiceMethod(myFileUploadControl.PostedFile.InputStream);
```

Comment: Cool thanks, though wouldn't there be some timeout issues with script execution times and such? I'm purely speculating.

Comment: I only tried it in local communication between 2 layers in the same app domain, but the point is: I think there is no other way of transferring binary file data between services. You can use some WCF magic to manage such challenges if they occur in your tests.