# resource sharing in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have 2 asp.net mvc2 projects in a solution. One is normal site for visitors use and the other one is admin back-end which is going to be separated by sub-domains like test.com and admin.test.com. The scenario is like admin will add a new item(e.g product) with image and test.com will use that image to display product. Both application are sharing one db. so there is no problem to get the item details that is coming from the db. but for item image that has been uploaded in admin directory(admin.test.com) - any idea how to get it from general domain(test.com) to display??
Also what is the best way of separating the resources like image files or even css or js files across sites and how to access them?

p.s.I'm using shared hosting.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you have the upload save to a folder on the test.com site? That would be the logical answer to me.

Comment: bcoz the requirements is that the resources has to stay some where else! crazy...i know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can upload to a third sub-domain or to the front end domain.
You upload to a physical folder. This folder can be an appSetting value or so.

So, you get similar settings to those in web.config appSettings:

```
<add key="ProductImagesPhysicalFolder" value="x:\websites\frontend\product-images" />
<add key="ProductImagesFolderUrl" value="http://frontend.com/product-images" />
```

Upload to the physical folder (given you setup permission in ISS to allow write access to that folder), and have a helper method like `GetProductImageUrl(string imageFilename)` to get the URL of the image given its filename (saved in DB).

Comment: Third sub-domain sounds interesting. There will be no problem to access the files. But could you please explain a bit more on how to upload in third sub-domain while keeping the best security approach in mind?

Comment: Whether you use a third sub-domain (which will be helpful performance-wise only if you have so many product images since requesting them is now separate from app code) or you post the frontend site directly, the steps are the same.

Comment: Make windows user for the app pool of the admin site, give that user full access to the images folder. The public front end site can only have read access to that folder. This should be secure enough.

Comment: I'm afraid that is not possible as I'm using shared hosting therefore cant create user!

Comment: OK. Can you add virtual directory? Maybe make virtual directory in the admin site with write permission to the same folder of the front end.

Comment: Shared hosting changes a number of things. Maybe instead of folder, have a web service in the front end website (or third sub-domain if you go for that) that takes the file and save it. You don't have to save the file. You can send it as stream. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976302/forward-file-upload-details-to-another-remote-service/2036583#2036583 and http://gurustop.net/blog/2008/02/18/unit-test-friendly-file-upload-handling-in-n-tier-applications/

Comment: owo! this explains what i need! Thank you Mohamed.