# How do I share common web resources between web applications in Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, web-applications, architecture

I have Two different Web Application in different solution **Admin.Presentation** and **Users.Presentation**.
i have some common css, and images to apply look and feel in both the application, so i want make it in a seperate solution **common.presentation**
and it also take some service reference according to my use.

[image]

No I have some question

1. In this condition How to Share common Web Resources among two different web application.
2. I got stuck in situation,during registration i am saving user images into directory and path of that directory saved in database along with userid.
   now if admin see daily user registration,userimage become unavailable for him so i also want to save these images to **Common.Presentation**.

Is it right approach?
Plase assist...!!

Comment: i found a similar question as yours here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4617143/resource-sharing-in-asp-net-mvc?rq=1